# How to make joomla appear on my apache server?

Tags: server, apache2, joomla

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to install joomla! on my local server to build a website which I will then transfer to a cloud server.  I don't fully understand how my own server works, and I have been making good use of a lot of online guides.

Currently using this guide: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/install-joomla-ubuntu-14-04-apache2-mysql-php-support/

So I have unzipped the latest (3.4.1) joomla full package in the /var/www/html/ folder.
Then I grant the permissions and restart apache.

Now in my browser I want to access my server and hopefully a joomla! Prompt page will help me install and whatnot.  But I can't get the joomla page to appear.  If I type in my isp I get a Claro Internet page, which shows my connection to the internet with my usb modem.  If I type in localhost, I get the apcahe2 Ubuntu Default Page.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache always displays some file.  If you don't specify a specific file, it will look in its root directory (by default `/var/www/html`, but that can be changed).  There is a hierarchy of filenames it will look for, such as `index.html`, which is the default page you see.  However, you can specify a different filename in the URL, such as `localhost/index.php`, which will load the file `index.php` instead.

I believe Joomla uses `index.php`, so try that.  If Joomla were in a directory such as `/var/www/html/MyWebsite`, then you would enter `localhost/MyWebsite/index.php` to load it.

Apache itself doesn't need to know whether you are running a Joomla site, or a Wordpress site, or whatever; it just needs to know what file to load.